# Recoil.js: share state between React instances?

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

I have to create multiple small React Apps that are modularly integrated on existing WordPress sites (using Shortcodes).

They might use the same state that is currently shared using `react-hooks-global-state`, which works fine.

However, since I've started using `Recoil.js` for other Apps, I'd like to know if it is or will be possible to also share global state (accross React instances) with it. The problem right now seems to be that we have to provide a `RecoilRoot` that must be nested above all components. Obviously, this doesn't work when having multiple React Apps, does it?

Thank you!

Comment: It does not work, you have to implement your own library that leverages `useRecoilCallback` and `useRecoilTransactionObserver` (currently unstable) to share and keep in sync the Recoil instance of all your React apps 